JUnit with playwright bdd and azure dev ops
I'm using JUnit repoter for automatic test runs in Azure Dev Ops, and I was wondering if it is possible to have BDD steps in the report so I can see them when I open test run in azure. Right now only scenario name is displayed and when I open it it's empty azure test run
It would be nice to have steps from scenario written here if possible empty test scenario details in azure
This is my configuration file but as far as I can see on the official site there isn't anything that I can add here to log steps also in the report playwright configuration

Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

@Ammar Karabeg, glad to see you in Stack overflow. I checked the scenario, and it could not be supported currently, please check the detail below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.


I was wondering if it is possible to have BDD steps in the report so I can see them when I open test run in azure. Right now only scenario name is displayed and when I open it it's empty

I'm afraid it's not supported.
As per the Junit Reporter doc for playwright test, it doesn't contain BDD or test steps in the results.xml file.
In addition, in Azure DevOps, when we use the PublishTestResults@2 task to publish the JUnit report file results.xml, it doesn't have any entry on the Summary or result page.
Hope it answers.
